# Get request to retrieve a file from my own web server

Tags: web

i am trying to do a get request to my webserver so i can retrieve a file, the file i want to retrieve is called venom.jpg and the webserver i am trying to connect to it on  `http://82.26.108.68/`

my get request so far is :

```
"GET /venom.jpg HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 82.26.108.68\r\n\r\n"
```

However all i get here is a return of

```
HTTP/1.0 404 Not found
```

what have i done wrong in my request ?

Thanks

Comment: Can we assume this is not a routing question?  Is 82.26.108.68 the actual IP address of your webserver?  and it has a direct internet connection with no router on your local network?

Comment: it is connected to the web through a router, when i go to 82.26.108.68 i can see the server etc but as commented below from the outside no one can see this so i am now unsure what is the problem

Comment: when I visit http://82.26.108.68 I am reaching a server, which i assume is yours, but it replies with a 503 Service Unavailable.  So assuming you have port forwarding correct (i.e. port 80 is forwarding to the correct local server) then you do have a specific server config issue.

Comment: Thanks i have looked into and i think it was just an issue of port forwarding, have rebooted the router and now can conenct to it using my phone on 3g and get back the right responce when using that request :)

Comment: Yes it appears to be working correctly now for both index and venon.jpg

Answer (score 1):

GET requests is what regular browser does to download a document. I've just typed `http://82.26.108.68/venom.jpg` in address bar and captured server's reply with Fiddler:

```
HTTP/1.0 404 Not found
```

Fix your server, it doesn't serve that file.